# How to update multiple rows with one query with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently running more database queries of update, like the following:

```
UPDATE table SET status = 1 WHERE id = 3
UPDATE table SET status = 1 WHERE id = 7
UPDATE table SET status = 1 WHERE id = 9
UPDATE table SET status = 1 WHERE id = 18
etc...
```

**Question:**

How is it possible to run these queries in one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to update some rows on a given list you can use [**`IN()`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html)

```
UPDATE table SET status = 1 WHERE id IN (3, 7, 18);
```

If instead you need to update all rows just don't add any `WHERE` conditions

```
UPDATE table SET status = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE table SET status = 1 WHERE id in (3,7,9,18,...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit general if you mean how to update multiple rows in one command in general it depends on your queries but if your question is more specific and you need to run 1 single query instead of all above queries you can try this :

```
 UPDATE table SET status = 1 WHERE id IN (3,7,9,18)
```